# How can I do logical operations on Rcpp::NumericMatrix using a "sugar" manner?

Tags: r, rcpp

I have to compare a matrix entry-wisely with a number, so I try to define a Cxx function such as

```
src <- '
LogicalMatrix f(NumericMatrix fmat, double t){
  LogicalMatrix result = fmat >= t;
  return result;
}
'
cppFunction(src)
```

But some exceptions are thrown out. What is the reason? So how can I do it in a tidy way?

Comment: Why can't you just compare matrix entry wise in R (e.g., `matrix(1:9, 3) > 3`)? And why oh why should it be in a tidy way?

Comment: Because this is one step in a Rcpp function, so I want a sugar-ish way to acheive it. Do u have any suggestion? @DavidArenburg

Comment: See below.  Sometimes it is both easiest _and fastest_ to simply use a loop as you get by with one and only memory allocation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer by @duckmayr is really spot-on, and shows an important detail: we may as well hide implementation detail *behind a function* because after all that is all *Rcpp Sugar* et al do for us anyway.

But we can rely on Sugar operation as desired by @zengchao if we first convert the matrix to a vector, operate on that vector and then restore a matrix.  That works because internally a matrix is just a vector with added dimensions (of order two; arrays generalise to more than two).

But it turns out ... that that version is (marginally) more expensive than just looping (and marginally cheaper than working on columns).  See below for complete details but a function `f3()` could be:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
LogicalMatrix f3(NumericMatrix fmat, double t) {
    IntegerVector dims = fmat.attr("dim");
    NumericVector v(fmat);
    LogicalVector lv = v >= t;
    return LogicalMatrix(dims[0], dims[1], lv.begin()); 
}
```

But the non-obvious element-wise `f2()` remains the fastest:

```
R> microbenchmark(f(mat, 1.0), f2(mat, 1.0), f3(mat, 1.0), times = 5e4)
Unit: nanoseconds
       expr min  lq    mean median     uq     max neval
  f(mat, 1) 873 992 1322.10   1042 1118.0 1493236 50000
 f2(mat, 1) 823 925 1195.49    975 1049.5 2068214 50000
 f3(mat, 1) 864 977 1288.68   1031 1114.0 1909361 50000
R>
```

*Moral*: The simple looping solution does the least copying of temporary objects and is fastest. Overall, the speed difference between all three hardly matters.

And for larger matrices the advantage of *not copying temporaries* gets more important:

```
R> mat <- matrix(sqrt(1:1000), 1000)

R> microbenchmark(f(mat, 1.0), f2(mat, 1.0), f3(mat, 1.0), times = 1e3)
Unit: microseconds
       expr   min    lq    mean median     uq    max neval
  f(mat, 1) 3.720 3.895 3.99972 3.9555 4.0425 16.758  1000
 f2(mat, 1) 1.999 2.122 2.23261 2.1760 2.2545 17.325  1000
 f3(mat, 1) 3.921 4.156 4.31034 4.2220 4.3270 19.982  1000
R>
```

Full code below.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
LogicalMatrix f(NumericMatrix fmat, double t){
    int n = fmat.nrow(), m = fmat.ncol();
    LogicalMatrix result(n, m);
    for ( int j = 0; j < m; ++j ) {
        result(_, j) = fmat(_, j) >= t;
    }
    return result;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
LogicalMatrix f2(NumericMatrix fmat, double t){
    int n = fmat.nrow(), m = fmat.ncol();
    LogicalMatrix result(n, m);
    for ( int i = 0; i < n; ++i ) {
        for ( int j = 0; j < m; ++j ) {
            result(i, j) = fmat(i, j) >= t;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
LogicalMatrix f3(NumericMatrix fmat, double t) {
    int dims[2] = { fmat.nrow(), fmat.ncol() };
    NumericVector v(fmat);
    LogicalVector lv = v >= t;
    return LogicalMatrix(dims[0], dims[1], lv.begin()); 
}

/*** R
mat <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4), 2, 2)
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(f(mat, 1.0), f2(mat, 1.0), f3(mat, 1.0), times = 1e5)

mat <- matrix(sqrt(1:1000), 1000)
microbenchmark(f(mat, 1.0), f2(mat, 1.0), f3(mat, 1.0), times = 1e3)
*/
```

*Edit:* And we can remove one more line relative to `f3()` but it makes little difference on run-time:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
LogicalMatrix f4(NumericMatrix fmat, double t) {
    IntegerVector dims = fmat.attr("dim");
    LogicalVector lv = NumericVector(fmat) >= t;
    return LogicalMatrix(dims[0], dims[1], lv.begin()); 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I assume by "tidy way" you mean avoiding loops in favor of using syntactic sugar provided in Rcpp. Since sugar provides a comparator with one value for vectors but not for matrices (see [here](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/blob/master/inst/include/Rcpp/sugar/operators/Comparator_With_One_Value.h) and [here](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/blob/master/inst/include/Rcpp/sugar/operators/logical_operators__Vector__primitive.h)), I think the most "tidy way" you can do for now is to loop (only) over columns (or rows), i.e., without having to loop over columns and rows:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
LogicalMatrix f(NumericMatrix fmat, double t){
    int n = fmat.nrow(), m = fmat.ncol();
    LogicalMatrix result(n, m);
    for ( int j = 0; j < m; ++j ) {
        result(_, j) = fmat(_, j) >= t;
    }
    return result;
}

> f(fmat, 1.0)
      [,1]  [,2]
[1,]  TRUE FALSE
[2,] FALSE  TRUE

> f(fmat, -1.0)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] TRUE TRUE
[2,] TRUE TRUE

> f(fmat, 2.0)
      [,1]  [,2]
[1,] FALSE FALSE
[2,] FALSE FALSE
```

However, I would suggest that avoiding the extra loop doesn't really buy you anything in terms of readability (and in fact may harm readability for some readers of your code); consider the function where you loop over rows and columns:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
LogicalMatrix f2(NumericMatrix fmat, double t){
    int n = fmat.nrow(), m = fmat.ncol();
    LogicalMatrix result(n, m);
    for ( int i = 0; i < n; ++i ) {
        for ( int j = 0; j < m; ++j ) {
            result(i, j) = fmat(i, j) >= t;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

I don't really see how this is significantly harder to type, it seems to be essentially performance equivalent (the mean execution time is slightly lower though the median is slightly higher -- see benchmarks below), and at least for some readers I bet it would be more readily apparent precisely what you're doing.

That said, if skipping a loop helps you out, I think this is the best you can do for now.

```
library(microbenchmark)

> microbenchmark(loop = f(fmat, 1.0), nonloop = f2(fmat, 1.0), times = 1e4)
Unit: microseconds
    expr   min    lq     mean median    uq      max neval cld
    loop 6.564 7.402  9.77116  7.612 8.031 9173.952 10000   a
 nonloop 6.425 7.123 10.01659  7.333 7.682 4377.448 10000   a

> microbenchmark(nonloop = f2(fmat, 1.0), loop = f(fmat, 1.0), times = 1e4)
Unit: microseconds
    expr   min    lq      mean median    uq      max neval cld
 nonloop 6.356 7.124 10.179950  7.333 7.544 4822.066 10000   a
    loop 6.775 7.404  9.588326  7.613 7.892 4278.971 10000   a
```

Comment: Since the size of matrix is very large, I want to improve the performance as much as possible.  But it seems that the sugar comparator for vector and a number has not much advantage in performance. 3gu very much @duckmayr.